# One git user local and remote, one git user only local

Tags: git

I read several questions about Git double accounts but did not find it or misunderstood what I should do or if it is even possible.

I use git with account A with email `A@mail.com` everything for SW development local and remote (github and BitBucket).

I want to create a second account, account B with if needed email b@mail.com, and use this only for KiCad locally. I do a daily *Drive/SSD user folder incremental* Backup to a remote NAS so no need for a GitHub remote account.

Is this possible? It's on a Mac where the SW-development and HW-development folders are subfolders from my user account and have no overlap anywhere, not even an alias.

Can I just create a second account locally?
With two accounts, will it conflict with other local directories?

Answer (score 0):

There are no "Git *accounts*". There's just Git *configuration*. You can configure whatever name and email you like (globally for your system, per-repository, or per-worktree) with `git config` (`--global`/`--system`/`--local`/`--worktree` – if unspecified, defaults to `--local`).

It can even be specified during commit with `--author` or via environment variables (`GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`).

These values are recorded with every commit and cannot be changed retroactively. They are completely independent from any hosting provider (e.g. GitLab) accounts or credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, Git itself has no concept of accounts. Accounts are only dded by services such as GitHub or BitBucket. As it seems that you only want to do a local clone of the repos, you could go ahead and do the following for each repository (SW and HW developement):

1. `cd` into the folder on your NAS where you want the backup to live, e.g., `cd /mnt/NAS/gitBackup`
2. Create a bare clone of your git repo: `git clone ~/git/softwareRepo --bare`
3. `cd` back into you local repo: `cd ~/git/softwareRepo`
4. Add your backup as a separate remote: `git remote add backup /mnt/NAS/gitBackup/softwareRepo`

To update the backup, you can now simply do `git push backup master` (much like you would do with `git push origin master` but replacing `origin` with `backup`)

Comment: Ah I just saw that you are using Mac and not Windows, I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you, I just want to work locally. Did make it more clear in my question. Sorry about that it was't 100% clear.